# Swift - CoreData - DetailViewController - passing an object

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, ios8

I'm creating a `CoreData` project.  I used the Master / Detail template from XCode6 (beta 5).  I've studied it for the past few days, and I'm confused on the `anyObject?` that it uses.  I am passing it an Event. As I did with Objective-C, I'd like to use `Event.eventName` in lieu of `detail.valueForKey("eventName").description`

I have tried numerous attempts and I now have something that works.  But does it work properly?  Is there a way to pass an Event (object) to the DetailViewController in a better (or more efficient) way than what I have?

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet var textFieldEventName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textFieldStartDate: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textFieldEndDate: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var labelNumberOfDays: UILabel!

    var currentEvent: Event!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateDisplay()
    }

    func updateDisplay()
    {
        if let textField = self.textFieldEventName
        {
            textFieldEventName.text = currentEvent.eventName
            textFieldStartDate.text = currentEvent.startDate
            textFieldEndDate.text = currentEvent.endDate
            labelNumberOfDays.text = "\(currentEvent.orderNumber)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you cast the `AnyObject?` to an `Event`? Since you know it's an event, that's what AnyObject is for

Comment: And that's where I'm getting a bit confused. On a Master / Detail template, they use var detailItem: AnyObject? and then if let detail: AnyObject = self.detailItem...  But if I try to do detail.startDate or detailItem.startDate it gives an error (AnyObject does not have a member named "startDate".  But the entity Event does have one, and that is what the prepareForSegue is sending it.  So how do I cast the AnyObject? to an Event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the relevant Swift documentation bit on [Type Casting for Any and AnyObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_498). In your case, here is one option:

```
let detail: Event = self.detailItem as Event
```

This is really extremely basic and you should read the Swift book a bit more before coding by example.

Comment: I know I had used either that or something similar.  What I had not done is changed it from an NSManagedObject to Event in the InsertNewObject, and that is why it had not worked for me before.  Thank you.